# Clarification on freeing memory in C

Tags: c, memory-management

I'm trying to free all my memory, and I'm not sure if I'm doing it properly for a struct*.  A snippet of my code:

```
struct words { char word[40]; };
int main() {
struct words* aList = malloc(2*sizeof(struct words));
// A text file is opened and each word is stored in a struct. I use an int variable to count how many times I've stored a word.//
if(n >= 2*sizeof(struct words) {
n = n*2;
aList = realloc(n*sizeof(struct words));
//Once my program is done, at the end of my main.//
free(aList);
```

From my understanding of C (I've only been using it for about 2 months), I've created an array of struct pointers at the start.  Then I'm dynamically increasing the size of the array with realloc.  When I free aList from memory, does it only free the addresses stored in aList?

Comment: That isn't a valid `realloc()` call. You're missing the original pointer. And to the question, `realloc()` or otherwise, the documentation on what `free()` does and what its requirements are [can be found here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free). `realloc()` has nothing to do with it, though its documentation is an [equally interesting read](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/realloc).

Comment: "I've created an array of struct pointers at the start." ― no. You've created an srray of struct. There's no array of pointers and no need to free its elements individually.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I did not directly cpy paste my code.  I do have the proper implementation of realloc (aList = realloc(aList, n*sizeof(struct words)) in my code.

Comment: @ec10 That's not proper yet. Proper would be to save the return value into a different variable, check if it is `NULL`, and if so, `realloc()` failed. Then the old memory with the old size is still valid. Otherwise, the new one counts and you can overwrite the old variable.

Comment: I'm using assert(aList) after every malloc and realloc.  Shouldn't this check for me?

Answer (score 2):

```
void* ptr = malloc(512);
```

This provides you with a block of memory which contains 512 bytes of data. That doesn't mean the block *is* 512 bytes big, it means that it contains 512 bytes or more.

Typically, each block has a small prefix which is used by the allocator.

```
struct MemoryBlock {
    size_t howBigWasIt;
    char   data[0]; // no actual size, just gives us a way to find the position after the size.
};

void* alloc(size_t size) {
    MemoryPool* pool = getMemoryPool(size);
    MemoryBlock* block = getFirstPoolEntry(pool);
    block->howBigWasIt = size;
    return &block->data[0];
}

static MemoryBlock blockForMeasuringOffset;
void free(void* allocation) {
    MemoryBlock* block = (MemoryBlock*)((char*)allocation) - sizeof(MemoryBlock));
    MemoryPool* pool = getMemoryPool(block->howBigWasIt);
    pushBlockOntoPool(pool, block);
}
```

Then understand that realloc is implemented by allocating a new block for the new size, copying the data over and releasing the old allocation.

So you can't release sub-allocations of an allocation:

```
int* mem = malloc(4 * sizeof(int));
free(int + 3); // invalid
```

HOWEVER.

```
int i = 0;
int** mem = malloc(4 * sizeof(int*));
mem[0] = malloc(64);
mem[1] = alloca(22); // NOTE: alloca - this is on the stack.
mem[2] = malloc(32);
mem[3] = &i; // NOTE: pointer to a non-allocated variable.
```

You are responsible for free()ing each of the allocations here.

```
// mem[3] was NOT an malloc
free(mem[2]);
// mem[1] was NOT an malloc
free(mem[0]);
free(mem);
```

but this is a matter of matching allocations to frees.